# Reference to Kotlin class property setter as function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

In the example below, `t::x` returns a reference to a property getter. How do I obtain the same for a setter?

```
class Test(var x: String) {}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val t = Test("A")

    val getter: () -> String = t::x
    println(getter()) // prints A

    val setter: (String) -> Unit = ????
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `t::x.setter`, it returns a `MutableProperty0.Setter<T>`, which can be used as a function:

```
val setter = t::x.setter
setter("abc")
```

Comment: Interestingly, this requires an additional dependency - `kotlin-reflect`

Comment: Is the code generated from `val getter: () -> String = t::x` differs from `val getter: () -> String = t::x.getter`

Comment: It is different, the latter has an extra method invocation on the `KMutableProperty0` interface (as you'd expect, this is what the code says). You can check this yourself by using `Show Kotlin bytecode` in IntelliJ (it's the `Tools -> Kotlin` menu).

Comment: Shame about asymmetry between ref to getter and ref to setter

Comment: For the record, see the suggested usage here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references-since-11 , which is symmetrical.

Comment: Thank you @zsmb13 , in my example `t::x` is already a bound property  .I don't see how the link you provided makes the usage symmetrical.

Comment: Well, as in the example uses `set` and `get` on the bound property instead of storing the getter and setter in a variable.

Answer (score 6):

The return type of `t::x` is `KMutableProperty0<String>`, which has a `setter` property, so you can do this:

```
val setter: (String) -> Unit = t::x.setter
setter("B")
println(getter()) // prints B now
```

Answer (score 5):

```
t::x::set
```

This works without `kotlin-reflect` because it doesn't call any external methods, unlike `t::x.setter`

Still, the cleanest code is generated when using lambda syntax.